# ¿Es posible conectar angular desde mi localhost con la base de datos en un hosting?

Tags: php, hosting

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en angular y estoy realizando unas pruebas. Quiero conectar mi aplicación desde mi localhost con la base de datos que tengo en 000webhost.com, pero me está dando errores. Cabe destacar que todo funcionaba correctamente si todo lo hacía en localhost de mi pc.
Al principio, pensaba que simplemente no había hecho correctamente las conexiones con la base de datos pero he mirado en un wordpress que tenía con el mismo proveedor y las conexiones son iguales.

Los errores:

1. POST https://nombre.000webhostapp.com/post.php net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
2. Http failure response for https://nombre.000webhostapp.com/post.php: 0 Unknown Error

Este es el código:

conexion.php

```
<?php

 class conexion_db{
    
    public function accesoDB(){

    $host = "localhost";
    $usuarios = "idxxxxxxxx_user";
    $clave = "password";
    $db = "idxxxxxxxx_db";

    try{
        $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $usuarios, $clave);
        $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $con->exec("set names utf8");
        return $con;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        $err = $e->getCode();
        $msj = $e->getMessage();

        //Muestra errores si los hay
        echo "ERROR: " . $err . " " . $msj . "</p></div>";
    }
    return $con;
}
  
}
?>
```

post.php

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT');

header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type");


    include_once "conexion.php";
    try{
        $jsoncontent = file_get_contents("php://input");
        $jsonQr = json_decode($jsoncontent, false);
        if (!$jsonQr) {
            exit("No hay datos");
        }

        $fecha_actual = date('d-m-Y');

        $consulta = "INSERT into asistentes (datos_registro, fecha_registro) values (?,?)";
        $basedatos = new conexion_db;
        $consulta_qr = $basedatos->accesoDB()->prepare($consulta);
        $resultado = $consulta_qr->execute([$jsonQr->value, $fecha_actual]);

        $json_pretty = json_encode($jsonQr->value, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

        echo $json_pretty;


    }catch(PDOexception $e){
            echo 'Se ha producido un error' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    
?>
```

Por favor, si os falta algo o me he explicado mal me lo decís para que rectifique. Gracias por tomaros vuestro tiempo en ayudarme.

EDIT: La aplicación funciona de la siguiente manera:
Yo tengo una aplicación angular, la cual utiliza una librería (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-scanner-qrcode) para generar un escáner qr. Entonces al escanear se obtiene un array, del cual me interesa el dato 'value', que es el que contiene la url que me interesa. Aquí una imagen para que veáis lo que se obtiene del escáner:

[image: Datos del escáner]

Una vez obtenido esto, y mediante una petición HTTP desde angular se envía el dato 'value' al post.php para que haga la consulta a la base de datos.

Comment: Hola. ¿Podrías mostrar qué datos mandas y desde dónde los mandas: URL, Postman u otro?

Comment: Hola qué tal. La aplicación en angular es un escáner qr, por ello lo que se manda al php es la url del código qr, que es un string. Todo esto se manda desde localhost:4200, es decir desde mi pc.

Comment: Pero, ¿tú has depurado ese string, en limpio, por ejemplo o mejor, has depurado lo que llega en el POST, poniendo algo como `var_dump($_POST);` sin más, obviando por el momento todo lo demás, conexión a la base de datos, etc?. Hay que buscar el motivo del fallo, por ejemplo, se podría estar generando un string demasiado grande que desborda la memoria permitida para peticiones POST o cosas así.

Comment: Yo me refiero a poner estas dos líneas **al principio** de tu archivo `post.php`, antes de los `header` y de todo: `var_dump($_POST);  return;` y verificar lo que eso arroja.

Comment: Devuelve los mismos errores de antes, no establece la conexión con post.php. La cosa es que si el post.php al que se le envían los datos está en mi pc y no en el hosting funciona.

Comment: Ya, pero lo que no logro entender ni ver en tu pregunta es el modo en que mandas los datos desde el lector de QR a la URL remota. Dicho sea de paso, no he trabajado nunca con lectores de este tipo y puede que de ahí mi ignorancia. Pero eso, sea como sea, no aparece claro en el contexto de la pregunta. ¿Podrías explicar como tomas los datos del QR?

Comment: No te preocupes, yo también soy ignorante. Voy a intentar explicar mejor todo el procedimiento en la pregunta de nuevo.

Comment: probá con `Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"` y `Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"`  ( agregando origin y options para q  valide el preflight del post )

Comment: Nada tampoco, los mismos errores.

Comment: Acabo de ver otra pregunta parecida a la mía en la que dice que no se puede conectar a mysql del hosting desde tu propio pc. Hay que pagar. Aquí la pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34610437/cannot-connect-to-database-000webhost. Y aquí en las FAQ de 000webhost.com para corroborar lo que digo: https://www.000webhost.com/website-faq/how-can-i-connect-to-mysql-from-my-computer-27